# Javascript GetElementById Set Value To Input

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, dom, model-view-controller

I am trying to set value to my input but I want to do this while my data ends. As you know id must be unique in html. So i created an 'element' variable and I am increasing it.
I want to make my input text my model's CustomerName.

That's my code.

```
var element = 0;
var HTML = "";
while (element !== 5) {
    HTML += "<input id=senderName" + element + " class=senderNameText type=text>";
    document.getElementById("senderName" + element).value = "@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerName)";
    element++;
}

            div.innerHTML = HTML;
            document.body.appendChild(div);
```

When I check it at console in Chrome it is written as "Cannot set property 'value' of null".

What should I do.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not actually adding the input html to the page in the `HTML +=` line, HTML is just a variable.  This causes `document.getElementById` to not find anything, resulting in the `.value` failing.

Comment: Hey, i cut some codes. It is adding actually. When i delete document.getelementbyıd part, it works fine. But i want to change the text as my customerName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like the following (note the quotes `'` in creation of he new inputs are necessary) :

```
var element = 0;
var HTML = "";

while (element !== 5) {
    div.innerHTML = "<input id='senderName" + element + "' class='senderNameText' type='text'>";
    document.body.appendChild(div);    

    document.getElementById("senderName" + element).value = "@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerName)";
    element++;
}
```

Now the problem come when you try to select new elements from the `document` and you're not yet append them so you get the message error that mean JS can't find any elements by the `ids` you're given.

So you should append the new HTML to the DOM inside loop.

Hope this helps.